# Unity not finding dll references

Tags: c#, visual-studio, interface, unity-container

We are doing a project that uses interfaces and Unity to resolve concrete implementations of classes.

My questions is the following: I need to get my dll's all into the same folder otherwise unity will not be able to resolve the interface etc. So according to me I have a couple of options:
1. Add the projects with the implementations as references and let VS copy the files to the output folder (for some reason this just feels like a hack)
2. Change the build location of all my projects to build to the same folder
3. Create a post build event to copy all the files needed to whereever they need to go

I have implemented to second option but this could lead to files in your build folder that should not be there. I am not a big fan of post build events, so I would like to ask from other people using Unity what they found to be the best solution for them.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The first approach sounds like the right one to me. Your project *does* depend on the implementation libraries; it doesn't express that dependency directly in code, but it requires them, so it seems reasonable to add a reference to them.

This is basically the same situation as where you've got three projects, where project A depends on project B, which depends on project C - you need to explicitly add project C as a reference within project A. Visual Studio doesn't work out transitive dependencies for you (at least it didn't the last time I checked).